# How to enable keyword info

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would like to know how can I enable keyword information on Visual Studio when I put the pointer mouse over a keyword, for example, a Access Specifiers.  On visual studio for Mac, this is enabled,  and shows brief information about that keyword as I get when I put the pointer over a class or method. On my Windows computer this is not enabled. Picture below shows how it works on my Mac:

[image: picture] .

Comment: Please explain keyword info

Comment: a brief succinct information about that keyword, as I get when I put the pointer over a class or method, for example.

Comment: what you want to enable is called "Intellisense". Look for it in the options, or find help online.